# Find element with class and add one more in php string

Tags: php, wordpress, class, audio, addition

I'm trying to make my own filter to audio shortcode in wordpress. I would like to **find an element with class and add one more**. I've got **string** with html code and str_replace doesn't work.

```
<div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg mejs-audio" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Audio Player" style="width: 416px; height: 30px;">
```

I would like to add '**test-class**' to div with '**mejs-container**'. I want to add that id ('mep_0') is not fixed.

Comment: You want to add `test-class` to EVERY `mejs-container` element?

Comment: Yes that's what i want

Comment: why doesn't str_replace work?

Comment: I don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Xpath](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php) for this purpose.

This is a simple example:

```
$dom = '<div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg mejs-audio" tabindex="1" role="application" aria-label="Audio Player" style="width: 416px; height: 30px;">
<div id="mep_1" class="mejs-container svg mejs-audio" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Audio Player" style="width: 416px; height: 30px;">
<div id="mep_2" class="mejs-container svg mejs-audio" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Audio Player" style="width: 416px; height: 30px;">';

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom); // read xml/html into dom to manipulate or search stuff
$elements  = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"mejs-container")]'); // search elements that contain "mejs-container" class

// loop through each found element 
foreach($elements as $element) {

    // get the current class attributes content 
    // which would give you "mejs-container svg mejs-audio"
    $currentClass = $element->getAttribute('class'); 

    // append "test-class" to the current value and set it in the dom (mind the space between classes)
    $element->setAttribute($currentClass . " test-class");
}
```

Comment: I still don't know how to do this :(

Comment: I added a comment to each line to explain what happens and also how $dom is set. You could also have it load HTML from a file using `$file = "test.html";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);` instead of the above first line. If you don't know how to mess with php stuff in wordpress, you could use javascript aswell to manipulate your tags.